# How to synchronize side-panel height to dynamic height?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-position

My side-panel height is not expanding when my div content's get bigger. I've given the height to 100% it's working fine for mobile view but for the desktop view, sometimes my sidebar's height is not increasing as it's fixed. But I want this height to be dynamic with content of my div. This is my whole code : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavis7/3e0qkb97/)

Here you can see, if you click the navbar, it's open the bar, and down below you will see side-bar and div content are not in the same height. This is the problem I'm getting :

[image]

I want side bar to expand. How can I resolve this? All I can say that I've to change this css class's height but how ?:

```
.sidepanel {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 0; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #221F20; 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    padding-top: 40px; 
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: the first problem, you don't want to add CSS property using JS.
the first solution is to use position relative in the parent element, the second solution is to use position fixed in your sidebar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

position should be fixed.

top 0 property solved the space issue.

added toggle inside the nav to toggle it when it opens, you only need to restyle the toggle that is inside the nav if you wish.

```css
.sidepanel {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #221F20;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 40px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
    <div class="navbar" >

        <a href="#" class="toggleButton"><i class="fa fa-align-left" style="color: #000;"></i></a>
        <p>
        user
        </p>

    </div>
 <div class="sidepanel">
     <a href="#" class="toggleButton"><i class="fa fa-align-left" style="color: #000;"></i></a>
    <!-- General panel -->
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-alt sidepanel-icon"></i>  General</a>

</div>

<div class="container-fluid px-5 mt-2" id="main">

    <div class="row py-4">
        <div class="col-md-6 page-title-div">
            <div class="page-header">
                  <h2>HTML</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row card py-4 rounded">


        <div class="col-md-6 page-title-div">
            <div>
                  <p>In HTML, there are two main types of lists:
                    unordered lists (<ul>) - the list items are marked with bullets
                    ordered lists (<ol>) - the list items are marked with numbers or letters
                    The CSS list properties allow you to:

                    Set different list item markers for ordered lists
                    Set different list item markers for unordered lists
                    Set an image as the list item marker
                    Add background colors to lists and list items
                    </p>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I can't give fixed position as you see, amid scrolling it will create some spaces just  the left side of the sidebar which surely is not a good design

Comment: i edited my answer, this will work for you for sure this time

Comment: it's not solving as if i give top 0 then, the navbar icon is not showing up. The whole sidebar is taking the space

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, you need to add a toggle button inside the side nav, to close it as i mentioned

Comment: Copy the html that i wrote

Answer (score 0):

if you add `position: relative` to your body, your problem should be solved.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //sidepanel navigation
    $(".toggleButton").on("click", function() {
        if ($(".sidepanel").css("width") == "0px") {
            var mainWidth = $("#main").width() - 256;
            $(".sidepanel").css("width", `15%`);
            $("#main").css("margin-left", `15%`);
            $("#main").css("width", `85%`);
        } else {
            $(".sidepanel").css("width", "0%");
            $("#main").css("margin-left", "0%");
            $("#main").css("width", "100%");
        }
    });

    //menu item navigation
    $(".menuItem").on("click", function() {

        // if this menuitem is collapsed
        if ($(this).next().css("height") == "0px") {

            // turning off all other menu items except for this
            $(".menuItem").not($(this)).next("div").css("height", "0px");
            $(".menuItem").not($(this)).removeClass("openAnchor");
            $(".menuItem").not($(this)).addClass("collapsedAnchor");

            // turning off all sub menu items except for this
            $(".subMenuItem").next("div").css("height", "0px");
            $(".subMenuItem").removeClass("openAnchor");
            $(".subMenuItem").addClass("collapsedAnchor");


            // substituting collapsed class for open class
            $(this).removeClass("collapsedAnchor");
            $(this).addClass("openAnchor");


            var numberOfChildren = $(this).next("div").find("> a").length;
            var height = 37 * numberOfChildren;
            $(this).next("div").css("height", `${height}px`);

        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("openAnchor");
            $(this).addClass("collapsedAnchor");
            $(this).next("div").css("height", "0px");
        }
    });

    // sub menu item navigation
    $(".subMenuItem").on("click", function() {

        // if this menuitem is collapsed
        if ($(this).next().css("height") == "0px") {

            // accesing sibling open anchor
            var openAnchorChildNumber = $(this).parent().find(".openAnchor").first().next("div").find("> a").length;
            var heightToDeduce = 37 * openAnchorChildNumber;
            console.log(heightToDeduce);
            // turning off all other sub menu items except for this
            $(".subMenuItem").not($(this)).next("div").css("height", "0px");
            $(".subMenuItem").not($(this)).removeClass("openAnchor");
            $(".subMenuItem").not($(this)).addClass("collapsedAnchor");


            // substituting collapsed class for open class
            $(this).removeClass("collapsedAnchor");
            $(this).addClass("openAnchor");


            var numberOfChildren = $(this).next("div").find("> a").length;
            var height = 37 * numberOfChildren;
            $(this).next("div").css("height", `${height}px`);
            var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height() + height - heightToDeduce;
            $(this).parent().css("height", `${parentHeight}px`);


        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("openAnchor");
            $(this).addClass("collapsedAnchor");
            $(this).next("div").css("height", "0px");
            var numberOfChildren = $(this).next("div").find("> a").length;
            var height = 37 * numberOfChildren;
            var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height() - height;
            $(this).parent().css("height", `${parentHeight}px`);
        }
    });

});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

/* The sidepanel menu */
.sidepanel {
    height: 100%; /* Specify a height */
    width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
    position: absolute; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #221F20; /* Black*/
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
    padding-top: 40px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidepanel .collapsedAnchor::after {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    float: right;
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f054";
}
.sidepanel .openAnchor::after {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    float: right;
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f078";
}

/* The sidepanel links */
.sidepanel a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #B7B6B8;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 13px;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidepanel a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidepanel .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

a.menuItem i.fa{
    font-size: 15px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left 0.5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .sidenav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

.sidepanel .subMenus {
    padding-left: 3%;
    /* position: fixed; */
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.subMenus a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <div class="navbar" >

        <a href="#" class="toggleButton"><i class="fa fa-align-left" style="color: #000;"></i></a>
        <p>
        user
        </p>

    </div>
 <div class="sidepanel">
    
    <!-- General panel -->
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-file-alt sidepanel-icon"></i>  General</a>

</div>

<div class="container-fluid px-5 mt-2" id="main">

    <div class="row py-4">
        <div class="col-md-6 page-title-div">
            <div class="page-header">
                  <h2>HTML</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row card py-4 rounded">


        <div class="col-md-6 page-title-div">
            <div>
                  <p>In HTML, there are two main types of lists:
                    unordered lists (<ul>) - the list items are marked with bullets
                    ordered lists (<ol>) - the list items are marked with numbers or letters
                    The CSS list properties allow you to:
                    
                    Set different list item markers for ordered lists
                    Set different list item markers for unordered lists
                    Set an image as the list item marker
                    Add background colors to lists and list items
                    </p>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: it partially solves my problem. But there are many other pages so if i give body position as relative it affects them. All I want is , for some page whole sidepanel is  shown with scrollbar.

Comment: recheck my answer, i resolved it without need to add css for the body